# Truncate Table C# Cannot Find Table - Does not Exist or no Permission

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm going to use my full table name because I'm trying to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong as to why the table can't be found.

I'm trying to truncate a table within C#. I am able to run this command, `"TRUNCATE TABLE NS_Vendor"` within SQL Server and it correctly finds and truncates the table.

If I try to do this in my C# application, I'm told does not exist or no permission. I'm using DB admin account so it can't be permission. I'm using the code below. I'm inside of the database named Public with admin user credentials and I'm looking to truncate the `"NS_Vendor"` table. The cmd below works in SQL Server. I've tried different strings like `"dbo.NS_Vendor"` amongst others but none of them work.

Would someone mind pointing out to me what I'm not understanding about what I'm doing wrong?

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server = server; Database = Public; User = ; Password = ;");
            string query = "TRUNCATE TABLE " + "NS_Vendor";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Is your connection string the same as the database you are connected to in SMSS?

Comment: In which line the error occurs and what is the exact error message?

Comment: Have you tried logging in using the same db admin account to SSMS and tried the truncate? Just trying to rule out that the user does have permission.

Comment: Yes it is. In the C# application I've already been adding and querying for data in the table I'm trying to truncate. I'm actually using the repository pattern with entity framework so I was using the main context to truncate. Couldn't get it to work so figured I'd get it to work this query way that I posted and then use the context.

Comment: Truncateing requires ALTER TABLE permission, this is higher than DELETE. Do you have this permission>

Comment: @Liam I have the user I'm using dbadmin. Figured that should cover it?

Comment: @DanielJackson I'm not familiar with EF you are using, but any chance it "remembers" an old schema you had changed? and therefore via the management studio things are ok but you code it trying to reference a non-updated schema?

Comment: @Y.S It's possible but that's why I'm using the code above. I'm not using EF with that code. Just straight connecting to a database and sending the query.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir The line is the `ExecuteNonQuery();` and the exact exception message is, `Cannot find the object "NS_Vendor" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

Comment: @DanielJackson: As Chris correctly pointed out you are the only one who can compare both the connection string you are using in sqlserver for truncating and in C#. Other than that everything looks fine. If you have access in sqlserver it should work in server side given you are using the proper credentials on both places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, i would suggest to do couple of things. At first try with this :

```
string query = "DELETE NS_Vendor";
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you still get similar error, then i think you are interacting with different database. But if it throws no error, then it is sure that your provided user does not have required permission for `TRUNCATE`

You can get some useful information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on `TRUNCATE TABLE` which indicates

> The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed server role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and are not transferable. However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE statement within a module, such as a stored procedure, and grant appropriate permissions to the module using the EXECUTE AS clause.

Comment: So I changed the query to `"DELETE NS_Vendor"` and it did not throw an exception. All I have left to try is giving every permission I can see. I just thought sysadmin would be enough but I suppose not.